# Is there any standard way to run a java project from intellij using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

When using gradle with intellij how am i supposed to run the project?
for example i can run it just right-click in the main class and hit run but:

- is there any other standard way of doing it?
- what task should i run to execute my project?
- the way all do it is just simple right-click and run the main() method?

Things to consider:

- created a gradle project (using intellij)
- inside that project i created a module with only one package and 1 class nothing more

Comment: Do you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44320306/738746?

Answer (score 0):

If your Java project has a "main" class, then you just need to apply the Application Plugin and execute the `run` task. See the [Gradle user manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:building_java_applications) for more details.